# How to fill a mvc dropdown with contentypecollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to show a dropdownlist with the content types available from my sharepoint host web.
Normally I would use in the html helper something like contentype.name but its not in the intellisense, I wonder if I should convert the contentypecollection to  a list before passing it to the view?

```
 public ActionResult Index() //Index fills the dropdown
    {
        var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);

        using (var ctx = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
        {
            ContentTypeCollection contentTypes = ctx.Web.ContentTypes;
            ctx.Load(contentTypes);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            return View(contentTypes);
        }    
    }
```

view

```
@model Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentTypeCollection
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ContentType";
}

<h2>ContentType</h2>

<h2>FillDropDwon</h2>
@Html.DropDownList("ContentTypeList", "????", "Select")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change properties of `Value` and `Text` to properties of ContentType

```
@Html.DropDownList("ContentTypeList", new SelectList(Model , "Value" , "Text"))
```